# *C* Acceptable 2D String input?

Tags: c, string, getchar

Is this an okay way to input strings of digits into a 2D array? I have a few questions regarding the code:

- The assignment is to input as many strings as the user would like until they enter an empty string. Then I need to `tokenize` and `atoi` the strings later on.
- Would it be better / easier to use 1D array and a `char **` to do it?
- And last, with the `char **`, if I allocate memory for the strings, do I have to allocate more / different memory for the tokens?

  ```
  int strInput ( char string[][], int maxChars )
  {
  int i = 0;

  printf("Enter strings of digits. Enter empty string to stop.\n");
  while (( string[i][maxChars] = getchar() )
  {
      printf("Please enter a string of digits:");
      i++;
  }
  string[i] = '\0';

  return i;
  }
  ```

Comment: @lpapp I thought I needed that first dimension to increment to move to the next array of characters. Ie. `string[0]` gets input. Then `i = 1;` so `string[1]` gets input, and so on. But I think I need to use a `char **` So I'm working on the code right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `char string[][]` K&R notation is ancient, you ought to use the "new" `char**` style, indeed.

> Is this an okay way to input strings of digits into a 2D array?

Definitely no. You are reading char by char rather than digit-string by digit-string, which I assume your intention was.

> Would it be better / easier to use 1D array and a char ** to do it?

It can be done that way, too, writing some token between the items in the same string. It is basically up to you.

> And last, with the char **, if I allocate memory for the strings, do I have to allocate more / different memory for the tokens?

Yes, sure, you either allocate a very large memory upfront or you keep reallocating.

Comment: You said I can use the array and char ** "too". What's the other way you're referring to?

Comment: @JordanLindsay: you can store a list of strings in an 1D "array" as well 2D depending on your personal preference. You do not need an in-between terminator for 2D arrays, but you inherently need one for 1D.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'm going to use a `char []` and `char **` because I think I'm getting the syntax figured out.